# get the information on the last closed iOS App

Tags: ios

I am working on an iOS App and have stumped on one of the odd requirement that my client would like to have. We want to exit from app A and open app B then close app B and open app A again, We are trying to get the name of the app B which was closed recently. Is this something that can be done? If yes, how do I accomplish this?
Thanks for all of yours help!

Comment: I thought so that this cannot be done. However if I have to get the information on the app that is playing music in background. For example while my app is open and I have music playing by pandora how would I get the name of the app that Pandora is the app playing music in background.  For now I am able to detect this by otherAudioIsPlaying but would like to know the name of the app that is playing audio. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get the last closed iOS app, but if you have two apps and you want to be able to move between the apps you may be able to use URL schemes. URL Schemes Documentation Here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18